# Minimum time for loading screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, loader

I'm trying to figure out how to work this out.. (super beginner here). I have a loading screen on my website that is visible while the page is loading, when it's done loading the div the loader is on gets hidden. I'd like to have some content on the loader, so I need it to stay on the screen for at least 5-8 secs before disappearing.

here's the code:

```js
//LOADING
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
        document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
};
```

```css
/*LOADER*/
#loader {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!--LOADING-->
<div id="loader"> Loader content </div>

<!--CONTENT-->
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

any help will be greatly appreciated, thank in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will display the loader content for 5 seconds before displaying the actual content. Only change was adding `setTimeout` to the code that runs after the document's readystate is set to "complete".

```js
//LOADING
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
        document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";
    }, 5000)
    }
};
```

```css
/*LOADER*/
#loader {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!--LOADING-->
<div id="loader"> Loader content </div>

<!--CONTENT-->
<div class="content">Content</div>
```